# Brew Variables for M1/Intel

Tags: macos, homebrew, intel, apple-m1

I'm working on a script to put into my MDM for Mac deployments that will install some development plugins. It seems like the homebrew path changes depending on whether or not the machine is M1 or Intel based. I've started writing an if/then script to change the brew path depending on the above, but I'm running into issues. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash

PROCESSOR=$(/usr/sbin/sysctl -n machdep.cpu.brand_string)
M1PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin/brew
INTELPATH=/usr/local/bin/brew

if [ "$PROCESSOR" == "Apple M1" ]
then
  brew=$M1PATH
else
  brew=$INTELPATH
fi

brew install cocoapods
brew install maven
brew eclipse-jee
brew elm
brew node
brew install python3
npm install -g react-native-cli
npm install --global gulp-cli
brew install vim
brew install watchman
brew install yarn
yarn global add jest
npm install -g appcenter-cli
brew install ios-deploy
```

Comment: Recently discovered some conveniences around `env -S-P...` which prompted me to revisit this; please see **Addendum 2024/03/14**

Answer (score 2):

I imagine the OP has since succeeded in their goal by now, but for those that need a solution, you just need to update the `PATH` variable with your 'detected` Homebrew path:

```bash
case `arch` in
    arm64) # M1
        export BREW_PREFIX=/opt/homebrew

    ;;
    i386) # Intel
        export BREW_PREFIX=/usr/local
    ;;
esac

export PATH="$BREW_PREFIX/bin:$PATH"
```

If like me you have scripts with the `#! /usr/bin/env bash` preamble, you may get extra mileage by adding a symbolic-link:

```bash
ln -snf $BREW_PREFIX/bin/{,brew_}bash
```

Then change your scripts to use `#! /usr/bin/env brew_bash`

**Addendum 2022/12/29**

The point of a new/temp environment variable is that we are at bootstrap i.e. when `brew` or any of its settings aren't yet known to the system.

In my personal setup, I have amassed a huge collection of convenience variables, functions, aliases and completions, so I have organised them into dedicated files, respectively; hence you don't see any eval/sourcing of `brew` hooks here and probably wouldn't even bother in a standalone-script.

**Addendum 2024/03/14**

Rereading the OP, the mistake here is that

```bash
if [ "$PROCESSOR" == "Apple M1" ]
then
  brew=$M1PATH
else
  brew=$INTELPATH
fi
```

sets an environment variables; the OP needs *aliases*, or otherwise needs to use those environment variables e.g.

Either set aliases and stick with original usage:

```bash
if [ "$PROCESSOR" == "Apple M1" ]
then
  alias brew=$M1PATH
else
  alias brew=$INTELPATH
fi
```

or instead stick with and use the environment variables:

```bash
$brew install cocoapods
$brew install maven
$brew ...
```

***Preferred Solution***

In hindsight, I think the easiest solution is to add both architecture variants to the PATH and the OS will find what it needs as per usual i.e.:

```bash
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH

brew install cocoapods
brew install maven
brew ...
```

Note, the OS does not care if a directory does not exist on the PATH e.g. `/opt/homebrew/bin` on *Intel* or `/usr/local/bin` on *M1*.

Comment: `HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY` variable provides the information.

Comment: I'm not so cruel as to vote down your answer, but I don't see the value it adds; see comment there.

Answer (score 0):

In Terminal enter `printenv` command.

You will notice `HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY` variable set to `/opt/homebrew` for Apple Silicon chip (M1, M2...).

No need to set an extra variable as `BREW_PREFIX`.

`HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY` does not seem to be set on Intel chip Mac, a workaroud could be

```bash
case $(arch) in
    arm64) # M1
        eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"

    ;;
    i386) # Intel
        # Warning: Homebrew's "sbin" was not found in your PATH but you have installed
        # formulae that put executables in /usr/local/sbin.
        # Consider setting your PATH for example like so:
        export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
        export HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY="/usr/local"
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: As you've pointed out, in one of the two scenarios, `HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY` does not exist, so you're back to relying on `arch` in a `case` statement; but frankly you've hard-coded the `BREW_PREFIX`/`HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY` in the `arm64` (M1) case, so what does your answer add? See addendum